# Joining two tables with conditon

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel-5

I have two tables:

```
users
- id
- fname
- lname
- is_online
```

and:

```
friendships
- friendA (references users)
- friendB (references users)
- status (1 means they are friends)
```

I want to query all friends of a given user who are online.

Comment: Sample data and desired results really help convey what you want to do.  And if you are learning SQL, you should include your attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Try INNER JOIN Query

Comment: SELECT T1.fanme,T2freindA, FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id WHERE T1.IS_ONLINE=1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
t1.*
FROM users t1
WHERE
t1.id IN (
    SELECT
    friendB
    FROM friendships
    WHERE
    friendA = CURRENT_USER_ID
    UNION
    SELECT
    friendA
    FROM friendships
    WHERE
    friendB = CURRENT_USER_ID
)
t1.is_online = 1
AND NOT t1.id = CURRENT_USER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    Unique(id) 
from 
    users outer join 
    friendships where 
        ((friendA = id and friendB = ID_TO_QUERY) or 
         (friendA = ID_TO_QUERY and friendB = id) and status = 1) 
        and is_online = true 
        and id /= ID_TO_QUERY
```